# Click button under Google-Chrome on Nexus 7

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, button, touch

Mouse-clicking the inside of a HTML button under Google-Chrome (with Nexus-7 emulation mode turned on)  on Windows 7 calls the expected event handler. On a physical Nexus-7 tablet (model 2012, Android 4.4.4), it is necessary to touch just below (**but outside**) the very same button to call the same event handler.

Firefox behaves correctly  on the Windows PC as well as on the Nexus-7 tablet.

It took me quite some probing before I discovered the soft spot underneath the button. It is rather annoying that touching **inside** the button doesn't give any result. Is there a workaround, or would an update to Android 5.0.2 fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Lollipop update shows every web content way different then every android version before. It uses a feature called "Android System WebView".

BUT: An upgrade to 5.x can destroy your device. I dont know if this still the case, but you should double check that.